# Give me suggestion about backup of schema and full backup in oracle

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-11g-r2

I need your help about backup in oracle database. Currently I am using Export Utility of Schema Backup but taking more time to complete and size is 40GB.

For full database backup using Image Copy and taking time more than 15 hours to complete and size is 650GB.

Which backup method is best for schema backup and full database backup which take less time and less size.

Database version Oracle Database 11gR2

Regards

Answer (score 0):

650*1024/15/3600 = 12.3 MB/s. Sounds like you have a 100 Mbit network connection for backup. In that case, using a compressed backupset instead of image copy will significantly reduce the time it takes to backup the database. – [Balazs Papp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/28019/balazs-papp)

Comment: Even better: do the export on the database server proper and avoid all that network overhead. And when you say you use “export utility” I hope that by that you mean Data Pump Export (expdp), not the old and deprecated exp tool ?